# Flutter: bottom widget when keyboard is displayed

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

It looks fine when the keyboard is hidden but when displayed the container is on top of it and it should be behind (not related to the content of the container):

```
   SafeArea(
                      child: Stack(
                        children: [
                          Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Expanded(child: child!),
                              Container(
                                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
                                height: 90.0,
                                child: NativeAdWidget(),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use **Scaffold** above your code, *change* it with **Material** widget, and the problem will gone. Just like this:

```
return Material(
  child: SafeArea(
    child: Stack(
      children: [
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(child: child!),
            Container(
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
              height: 90.0,
              child: NativeAdWidget(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: In the screen or widget where your text fields are, you have to remove Scaffold. I had the same problem, and after days, that was my fix.

Comment: I put it exactly like that